# Why can't I scroll in the terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 Cinnamon. After repositioning a terminal window (GNOME Terminal 3.18.3), I suddenly can't scroll up through the terminal output.

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> writes `2~` on the command line instead of scrolling
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> writes `A` on the command line instead of scrolling
- The scrollbar on the right fills the entire vertical height of the window, indicating that there's nothing to scroll back to.

As more output is added, none of the above changes. What messed up and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you reliably reproduce that or does the problem go away when reloading the terminal? Are you inside a tmux session, perhaps?

Comment: I don't know how to reload the terminal, and searching isn't helping.  If I open a new terminal, it doesn't show this behavior.  I'm not in a tmux session.

Comment: The terminal emulator got stuck on its _alternate screen_ for whatever unknown reason.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@James Henstridge's answer to [this AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123206/terminal-output-scrolling-is-gone-headless-11-10-server-upgraded-from-10-10) seems to identify the error correctly as the terminal getting stuck in a "cursor addressing" mode, whatever that means.

His first solution, the command `$ tput rmcup`, works, though there's not much in the way of explanation.  So, I attempted to figure that out.

`man tput` tells us that

> The `tput` utility uses the `terminfo` database to make the values of terminal-dependent capabilities and information available to the shell (see  sh(1)), to  initialize  or  reset  the  terminal,  or  return  the long name of the requested terminal type.

`terminfo` is also not very usefully documented.  The most comprehensive source I can find is a [tldp.org article](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Text-Terminal-HOWTO-16.html).  Evidently `terminfo` is a database of different terminals and what commands and capabilities they have.  Presumably every Linux installation has one?  So you can use different terminals?

`man terminfo` indicates its files are in `/etc/terminfo/*/*`, but on Ubuntu 16.04 I found only a README there.  The real files are in `/lib/terminfo/*/*`; e.g. `/lib/terminfo/l/linux`, which is probably the most relevant file for most readers?  I can't tell, because these files are not human-readable.  The tldp.org article linked above states that `infocmp` can be used to see their source, but that isn't true:

```
$ infocmp /lib/terminfo/l/linux
infocmp: couldn't open terminfo file /lib/terminfo/l/linux.
```

The article also mentions source code files `/etc/termcap` and `/etc/terminfo.src`, but these do not exist in Ubuntu 16.04.  I did find a set of `/usr/share/vte/termcap*/` directories that contain human-readable `xterm` files.  I'd have to guess that this all connects to the GNOME Terminal I'm using that's default to Ubuntu, but I'm tired of trying to figure out how.

The `man` page for `terminfo` does have one more helpful jot, though.  Under its 'Predefined Capabilities' is a 'Variable String' `exit_ca_mode` with 'capname' ("capability name", I assume) `rmcup` with the description `strings to end programs using cup`.  The description isn't very helpful, but the variable name is; this must refer to a terminal's capability to exit 'cursor addressing mode', which is what the terminal is stuck in.

So, `$ tput rmcup` must use `tput` to access the `terminfo` database and activate the current terminal's `exit_ca_mode` capability `rmcup`, which kills the cursor addressing mode and returns the terminal to its normal scrolling behavior.

Comment: Does this reset the scrollback buffer like the other `reset` answer? I want to be able to scroll up to see what is there and caused an error in the first place.

Comment: @Kvothe It's been so long I don't remember, and this hasn't happened to me since.  Good question, though.

Comment: scrollback is not reset with `tput rmcup`.

Answer (score 39):

To reinitialize the terminal, a simple `reset` will fix this. For more info and options,  `man reset`.

Beware: This will clear the scollback buffer.

Comment: Simple and works (tried on MacOS Terminal ssh-ed to Debian VM)

Comment: Tried on Ubuntu 20 and works

Comment: Although it works, it clears the past outputs

Comment: Worked on zsh + Ubuntu 22

Comment: It clears the history, which s****.

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem on Gnome terminal 3.28.2 (on Ubuntu 18.04). Simply Use Terminal (menu item) -> "Reset and Clear". Then you may also go into menu Edit-> Preferences-> Scrolling (tab) and enable scroll bar & set number of scroll lines

Answer (score 2):

None of the previous commands helped me (reset, etc.), so I tried this one, and it worked.

Open any Ubuntu, Bash, Windows Terminal version, and do the following.

1. Right-click in the top bar (where Ubuntu's logo is.)
2. Click on 'Properties.'
3. It will open a white interface with some menus.
4. Click the 'Layout' menu.
5. Inside of it, there's a section named 'Screen Buffer Size.' The said area has 3 options. Width: Height: and a box to check 'Wrap text output on resize.'
6. HERE! On 'Height,' you will erase any number that is placed, and you will write 9,000.
7. You're ending result should be Heigh: 9,000.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the "screen" command, then pressed control+a, then esc, which then allowed me to either us page up/page down to scroll up/down by the whole screen, or up/down arrow line by line

Comment: "Must be on a window layer"

Answer (score -2):

the way to fix it is to update and upgrade all the packages. Usually this happens because one of the packages in dpkg is corrupt. This happens on Kali Linux OS version 2020.3 sorry if the problem persists